# code working in one phtml file not working in another

Tags: php, database, javascript, ajax, multi-vendor

As this is marketplace multi vendor site, we are displaying vendor product information in frontend.

List of products informations are displaying as in image :

[image]

If we want to edit any information like "`Product name, Price, sku, qty....etc"`, at the last column, you can see "**Action**" column, below that there is a Edit button, we will click on that and new page will open as below image :

[image]

than we will enter the new "Qty value" and click on "save" button. Its working awesome without any problem.

we are using this code for editing quanity button : `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/mpassignproduct/editassignproduct.phtml`

```
<li class="fields">
<div class="customer-name">
<div class="field">
<label class="required" for="qty"><em>*</em><?php echo $helper->__('Quantity')?></label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" value="<?php echo intval($mpAssignProductModel->getQty()) ?>"
 class="required-entry validate-zero-or-greater input-text"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

but i want to provide an option to edit the quantity without clicking the "Edit" button present below "Action" column. in the 1st image , you can see "edit" button below "Qty". once we click on that, its displaying as following image :

[image]

once we change the value and click on "Update" buton, it show the updated value.
but once we refresh the page, it show old value only.

I used same code in mpassignproduct.phtml . but it didt worked for me.

means **code worked editassignproduct.phtml didt worked mpassignproduct.phtml**

or did i missed some code ?

so we used following code for editing qty, but this also same problem.

```
`app/design/frontend/default/default/template/mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct.phtml`  [full code : http://pastebin.com/TSd7CVxC ]
```

**PHtml**

```
    <td>
    <span class="label qty" id="valueqty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>">
        <?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>
    </span>

    <input type = "text" id = "qty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" 
    name="stock" value="<?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>" style="display:none;"/>

    <span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>">
        <img onclick="showField('<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>'); return false;" 
        src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
    </span>

    <p id="updatedqty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red;">Updated</p><br/>

    <button id="update_button_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" 
    onclick="updateField('<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>',<?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>); return false;" style="display:none" >
        <span>
            <span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span>
        </span>
    </button>

    <button id="reset_button_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" 
    onclick="hideReset('<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none"></button> 
</td>
```

**Script**

```
function hideReset(product_id)
    {
        var qtyId='#qty_'+ product_id;
        var editLink="#edit_link_"+ product_id;
        var updateButton="#update_button_"+ product_id;
        var resetButton="#reset_button_"+ product_id;

        $wk_jq(qtyId).hide();
        $wk_jq(editLink).show();
        $wk_jq(updateButton).hide();
        $wk_jq(resetButton).hide();
    }

    function showField(product_id)
    {
        var qtyId           = '#qty_'+ product_id;
        var editLink        = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
        var updateButton    = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
        var resetButton     = "#reset_button_"+ product_id;

        $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
        $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
        $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
        $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
        $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

        return false;
    }



    function updateField(product_id,assignqty)
    {

    //  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        var qtyId           = '#qty_'+ product_id;
        var valueId         = '#valueqty_'+ product_id;
        var updatedqty      = '#updatedqty_'+ product_id;
        var editLink        = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
        var updateButton    = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
        var resetButton     = "#reset_button"+ product_id;
        var url             = '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateField/')?>';

        $wk_jq(qtyId).toggle();
        $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
        $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
        $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

        $qty = $wk_jq(qtyId).val();
        jQuery(valueId).html($qty);
        hideReset(product_id);

        var tmpQty = assignqty+parseInt($qty) ;

        new Ajax.Request(url, {
            method: 'post',
            parameters: {id: product_id, qty: tmpQty},
            onComplete: function (transport) {
            //  alert(tmpQty);
                jQuery(priceId).val($price);                
        jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
                $updateButton.prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    }
```

**controllers.php**

```
public function updateFieldAction(){

            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
            $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
            $selllermpassignproduct=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($id);
            $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
            $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
            //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditProductId($id);
            if($selllermpassignproduct['seller_id']==$customerid)
            {

             $assignqty=isset($selllermpassignproduct['assignqty'])?$selllermpassignproduct['assignqty']:0;
             $newq=$pro->getQty()-$assignqty;
             $newqty=$this->getRequest()->getParam('qty')+$newq;
             $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
             $connectionWrite = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_write');
             $table1 = $connectionresource->getTableName('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct');

            $connectionWrite->beginTransaction();

                      $data = array(

                          'assignqty' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty'),


                      );

                      $connectionWrite->update($table1, $data, array(
                              'seller_id = ?' => $customerid,
                              'mageproductid = ?' => $id,


                          ));
                      $connectionWrite->commit();

            }else {

            $assignqty=isset($selllermpassignproduct['assignqty'])?$selllermpassignproduct['assignqty']:0;
            $newqty=$this->getRequest()->getParam('qty')+$assignqty;

            }
            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
            $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
            $stockItem->setData('qty', $newqty);

            $stockItem->save();

            $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 
            //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));
          }
```

there are JS errors in console, is there any chance because of following js code , quantity is not saving ? if so how to resolve these errors.

[image]

Comment: how many time you posted this question i think it's already solved

Comment: No, this is related to assign product, you only solved normal products , its asigned products

Comment: you have update the  assign product too with qunatity

Comment: add this table information.. mpassignproduct

Comment: please check here : http://prntscr.com/adcz1k

Answer (score 3):

you have to update the assign quantity too

```
 public function updateFieldAction(){
            //echo "gfggggg";
            //die;
            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
            $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
            $selllermpassignproduct=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($id);
            $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
            $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
            //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditProductId($id);
            if($selllermpassignproduct['seller_id']==$customerid)
            {

             $assignqty=isset($selllermpassignproduct['assignqty'])?$selllermpassignproduct['assignqty']:0;
             $newq=$pro->getQty()-$assignqty;
             $newqty=$this->getRequest()->getParam('qty')+$newq;
             $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
             $connectionWrite = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_write');
             $table1 = $connectionresource->getTableName('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct');

            $connectionWrite->beginTransaction();

                      $data = array(

                          'assignqty' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty'),


                      );

                      $connectionWrite->update($table1, $data, array(
                              'seller_id = ?' => $customerid,
                              'mageproductid = ?' => $id,


                          ));
                      $connectionWrite->commit();

            }else {

            $assignqty=isset($selllermpassignproduct['assignqty'])?$selllermpassignproduct['assignqty']:0;
            $newqty=$this->getRequest()->getParam('qty')+$assignqty;

            }
            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
            $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
            $stockItem->setData('qty', $newqty);

            $stockItem->save();

            $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 
            //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));
          }
```

Comment: i replaced this function in controllers, but it didt worked. can i use same function for both normal and assigned products?

Comment: yes do some debug with check the for error and other thing what quantity is updated or not

Comment: okay, i will try and inform you.....

Answer (score 1):

There is an exit() before you save()

Comment: i removed it, but still it did't worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a logical problem regarding the "ids" and another problem when reloade the page.
in your code you are using this custom model

```
Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')
```

in the phtml file you use:

```
<button id="update_button_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" 
onclick="updateField('<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>',<?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>); return false;" style="display:none" >
    <span>
        <span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span>
    </span>
</button>
```

after than in the js file you write :

```
function updateField(product_id,assignqty)
```

but **$assinproducts->getId()** IS NOT the product id but the id of the mpassignproduct entity.
you should use **$assinproducts->getProductId()** to get the product id.

The controller will then update correctly the product quantity in the stock item but when you refresh the page you are showing:

```
<span class="label qty" id="valueqty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>">
    <?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>
</span>
```

you are usng the **$assinproducts['qty']** value and not the product->stockitem->qty so I think that your controller MUST UPDATE both the product stock and the assinproducts['qty']

Hope this help
Giuseppe

Comment: as you said, instead of `$assinproducts->getId()` , i tried this code : `$assinproducts->getProductId()` and please give me updated code for controllers to use both `$assinproducts['qty']` & `product->stockitem->qty`