# Create custom url

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-vendor

Currently, I'm using Webkul extension for multi vendor. So the seller collection is available following link :
 http://example.com/marketplace/seller/profile/shopname
But, I want to change this url like this:
 http://example.com/shopname

Please help needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code I will do my best to answer. What you need to do is setup a new route and in that controller in the indexAction method you need to call the current method with any parameters.

So in Magento a URL is structured as follows:

$base/$controller/$method/$parameters
e.g. catalog/product/view/id/1 would be Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction() and $_GET['id'] = 1

So if you take your current URL it could be

1. marketplace = controller
2. seller = method
3. profile - parameter key
4. shopname = parameter value

It could also be that the controller is a sub directory calling the shopName method or the indexMethod.

So if you were to create a custom controller you create a module and do the following.

#### 1. Register the route

In your etc/config.xml file you would add the following (change colin_core to vendor_package name)

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <colin_core>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Colin_Core</module>
                    <frontName>shopname</frontName>
                </args>
            </colin_core>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

#### 2. Create Controller

So you need to create your IndexController under app/code/local/Vendor/Package/controllers/IndexController.php

So in the example below I am loading a product with an ID of 1. You need to replace the controller path and the code with Controller you are calling the code from and also the method with params you need to call.

```
//@TODO replace controller
require_once 'Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php';

class Colin_Core_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //@TODO replace code
        $this->getRequest()->setParam('id', 1);
        $controller = new Mage_Catalog_ProductController(
            $this->getRequest(),
            $this->getResponse()
        );
        $controller->viewAction();
    }
}
```

Please note that if you don't pass in a request and a response they would both be set to null when you call the controller.

Comment: if i need like this `http://example.com/market/shopname` Then what can i do?

Comment: What you need to do is change frontName to market in the config.xml and change indexAction to shopnameAction.

Answer (score 0):

That can be done using vendor profile as described in the user guide of the module Please check http://webkul.com/blog/magento-multi-seller-marketplace/#wkid7
also Please check the screenshot for more detail
[image]

Vendors can edit the urls as per their choice . Still have any doubt or query please let us know at our support ticket system http://webkul.uvdesk.com/

**Note - We are the developer of webkul's magento marketplace multi vendor module . We are not self promoting our product as customer asked the question specifically about webkul's product thats why we are describing with links**

Comment: we are using webkul marketplace extension can you please help here too : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92656/quantity-is-not-saving-in-database

Comment: Please raise a support concern and we will check that out thanks